# Discuss about how Keepalived call SpringCloud Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud

Is is right to set up the architect by using Keepalived and SpringCloud Zuul (work as gateway)?

Previously our architect is Keepalived + Nginx + Tomcat as shown below.

[image]

For now, we plan to use SpringCloud, nginx will be replaced by SpringCloud Zuul since Zuul (Ribbon) has similar functions as Nginx and we don't have very high concurrent requests. The new architect shows below

[image]

The questions are:

1. Is this design OK or any better designs?
2. Keepalived has to use IP points to SpringZuul, is it possible to use serivce name? If yes, what addtional softwares should be used?

Comment: any new about this question? I want to know too.